# What is the best way to seperate elements in HTML to minimize one element affecting another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have written a password form in HTML and it has some good functionality however, i have just made a change and the css is effecting the elements. basically when i click on the different input boxes it effects the labels of my form by shifting them slightly up to down.

here is a jsfiddle so people can see the change visibly. 
https://jsfiddle.net/b6hv8wLh/

here is some code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron" id="firstform">
    <h1>Sign up page</h1> 
    <form id="myform">

        <label>Username </label> <input type="text" name="uname" class="f1input" id="uname" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Username must be unique" class="mytooltip"><br>

        <div class="pwordCheck">
            <label>Password </label> <input type="password" class="f1input" id="pword" data-placement="bottom" title="" onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-original-title="Password must be more than 6 characters long" class="mytooltip"><br>
            <label>Confirm Password </label>  <input type="password" class="f1input" id="confpword"  onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Passwords must match" class="mytooltip">
            <span id="themessage" class="themessage"></span><br> 
        </div>

        <label>Email </label> <input type="email" class="f1input" id="e-mail"/><br>
        <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select job
              <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Java Developer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SQL Developer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tester</a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>
        <label>Job Role</label> <input type="text" class="f1input"/><br>

        <label>Age </label> <input type="number" class="f1input" id="age" oninput="ifOfAge(); return false;"/><br>

        <label>Can you drive? </label> <input type="text" class="f1input" id="drive" disabled/><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="usernameAlreadyExists(); return false;"/>
    </form>  

  </div>
```

i have tried wrapping my form in various divs and trying to hit indivdual elements but it is still making changes. just to make clear, i am trying to get it to a stage where the user clicks the input and the labels do not change at all.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by you assigning the `border:4px solid red;` styling to your input on focus.  This causes the input's overall size to become larger which moves down the elements below it.

One way to prevent this is to give the input 4px border the same colour as the background.  The border will then change to red on focus and become visible but the size will not have actually changed:

```
    input {
      background-color: #fff; 
      margin-left: 10px; 
      margin-bottom: 10px; 
      padding-right: 50px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      border:4px solid #D8D8D8;
    }
```

It's the additional `border:4px solid #D8D8D8;` declaration which makes the difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of border of input field when focus. Hence add border property for input field with same background color of the form.

```
input {
    border:4px solid #D8D8D8; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Immediate solution

In your case, the fix is really simple. The border size of the input boxes should not change when they are in focus.

So, for example the inputs on focus have this style:

```
border: 4px solid red;
```

But when they are out of focus, they do not have a border. So you should set a 4px border with the same color as the background when it is not in focus.

#### Bootstrap-like solution

Alternatively, you should consider using a single pixel border, with a box shadow instead. Just like Bootstrap does it, which you use as I see. IMHO this does *look great*, especially in contrast with these huge borders.

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-shadow` no need for any extra CSS with this.

```css
/* CHANGE BORDER TO BOX SHADOW ON THE FOCUS */
.f1input:focus{
 outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px red;
 border-radius: 15px;
}


body {
 background-color: #080808;
}
/*
.navbar-brand {
 background-color: red;
}
*/
.container-fluid{
 background-color: #006600;
 border: 0;
}

#websiteName a{
 color: black;
 font-size: 20px;
}

#websiteName a:hover{
 color: red;
}

#theLinks ul li a{
 color: black;
 font-size: 20px;
}

#theLinks ul li a:hover{
 color: red;
}


#firstform{
 background-color: #D8D8D8;
}

#firstform span{
 position: absolute;
}

.glyphicon-search
{
   position:relative !important;
}

#firstform .themessage{
    position: absolute;
}


#firstform {
 width: 60%;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}

#firstform h1{
 text-align: center;
} 

#firstform label{
 text-align: left;
} 

#myform {
 width: 100%;
}



input {
background-color: #fff; 
margin-left: 10px; 
margin-bottom: 10px; 
padding-right: 50px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron" id="firstform">
    <h1>Sign up page</h1> 
    <form id="myform">
  
  <label>Username </label> <input type="text" name="uname" class="f1input" id="uname" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Username must be unique" class="mytooltip"><br>
  
  <div class="pwordCheck">
   <label>Password </label> <input type="password" class="f1input" id="pword" data-placement="bottom" title="" onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-original-title="Password must be more than 6 characters long" class="mytooltip"><br>
   <label>Confirm Password </label>  <input type="password" class="f1input" id="confpword"  onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Passwords must match" class="mytooltip">
   <span id="themessage" class="themessage"></span><br> 
  </div>
  
  <label>Email </label> <input type="email" class="f1input" id="e-mail"/><br>
  <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select job
     <span class="caret"></span></button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Java Developer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SQL Developer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tester</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <label>Job Role</label> <input type="text" class="f1input"/><br>
  
  <label>Age </label> <input type="number" class="f1input" id="age" oninput="ifOfAge(); return false;"/><br>
  
  <label>Can you drive? </label> <input type="text" class="f1input" id="drive" disabled/><br>
  
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="usernameAlreadyExists(); return false;"/>
 </form>  
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

    #myform{
      width: 450px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .sep{
      padding: 10px;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #080808;
    }
    /*
    .navbar-brand {
      background-color: red;
    }
    */
    .container-fluid{
      background-color: #006600;
      border: 0;
    }
    #websiteName a{
      color: black;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    #websiteName a:hover{
      color: red;
    }
    #theLinks ul li a{
      color: black;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    #theLinks ul li a:hover{
      color: red;
    }
    #firstform{
      background-color: #D8D8D8;
    }

    #firstform span{
      position: absolute;
    }
    .glyphicon-search
    {
       position:relative !important;
    }
    #firstform .themessage{
        position: absolute;
    }
    #firstform h1{
      text-align: center;
    } 
    .sep label{
      padding: 10px;
    }
    input {
    background-color: #fff; 
    margin-left: 10px; 
    padding-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: none;
    }
    .f1input:focus{
      outline: none !important;
        border:4px solid red;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }
    input#occupation{
      background-color: #999;
    }
    .mytooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
      background-color: #f00;
    }
    label{
        display:inline-block;
        width:150px;
    }
    /*
    @-webkit-keyframes example{
      25% {color: black;}
      50%   {color: yellow;}
        75%   {color: green;}
        100%   {color: red;}
    }

    #firstform h1{
        color: red;
        -webkit-animation-name: example; 
        -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    }*/
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }#myCarousel {
      width:50%;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: red;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #myCarousel item {
      text-align: center;
    }

        enter code here

    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron" id="firstform">
        <h1>Sign up page</h1> 
        <form id="myform">
            <div class="sep">
            <label>Username </label> 
            <input type="text" name="uname" class="f1input" id="uname" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Username must be unique" class="mytooltip">
            </div>
            <div class="pwordCheck sep">
                <label>Password </label> <input type="password" class="f1input" id="pword" data-placement="bottom" title="" onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-original-title="Password must be more than 6 characters long" class="mytooltip"><br>
                <label>Confirm Password </label>  <input type="password" class="f1input" id="confpword"  onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Passwords must match" class="mytooltip">
                <span id="themessage" class="themessage"></span><br> 
            </div>
            <div class="sep">
            <label>Email </label> <input type="email" class="f1input" id="e-mail"/>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown sep">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select job
                  <span class="caret"></span></button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Java Developer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SQL Developer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tester</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sep">
            <label>Job Role</label> <input type="text" class="f1input"/>
            </div>
            <div class="sep">
            <label>Age </label> <input type="number" class="f1input" id="age" oninput="ifOfAge(); return false;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="sep">
            <label>Can you drive? </label> <input type="text" class="f1input" id="drive" disabled/>
            </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="usernameAlreadyExists(); return false;"/>
        </form>  `enter code here`
      </div>
```